# Given 3 function values of $\phi :\mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}$ determine if $\phi$ is linear

Tags: linear-algebra

The problem is from [this book](http://web.stanford.edu/~boyd/vmls/).

> Let $\phi :\mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}$.
>   Given $\phi(1,1,0) = -1$, $\phi(-1,1,1) = 1$, $\phi(1,-1,-1) = 1$ determine if $\phi$
>
> a) must be linear,
>
> b) could be linear,
>
> c) cannot be linear.

I can see that:

$$\phi(1,1,0) + \phi(-1,1,1) + \phi(1,-1,-1) = 1$$

is different from:

$$\phi(1 - 1 + 1, 1 + 1 - 1, 0 + 1 -1) = \phi(1,1,0) = -1$$

And so:

$$\phi(x + y + z) \neq \phi(x) + \phi(y) + \phi(z)$$

Where $x$, $y$ ,$z$ are respective vectors from the problem definition.

Based on the above, am I correct to say that the function cannot be linear?

Comment: If $\phi$ is a function of three variables, how do you define $\phi(x+y+z)$?

Comment: x = [1, 1, 0], y = [-1, 1, 1], z = [1, -1, -1] <- inputs to the 3 given $\phi$ values. $\phi(x+y+z)$ is the same as $\phi(x)$, since y + z = [0, 0, 0]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct. By the way, since for any linear function $\phi(0,0,0)=0$, you may just consider
$$\phi(-1,1,1) + \phi(1,-1,-1)=1+1=2$$
which is different from
$$\phi(-1+1,1-1,1-1)=\phi(0,0,0)=0$$
So $\phi$ can not be linear.

Comment: $\phi(0,0,0) = 0$ is always true for linear functions, right?

Comment: @Amade Yes, that is true. It follows from homogeneity $f((0,0,0))=f(0\cdot (0,0,0))=0\cdot f((0,0,0))=0$.

Answer (score 3):

It can't be linear because $\phi(-x)=-\phi(x)$ for linear functions. Since $-1≠1$ for reals we're done.